# python: pandas install errors

Tags: python, compiler-errors, installation, pandas

I have the academic distribution of `EPD 7.1` for `MacOS 10.6.x`, which has pandas `0.3` version. The latest official version is `0.5.0` so I though I would upgrade to the latest.

Here is what I did:

1. saved the `zip` file of the source from [here](https://github.com/wesm/pandas)
2. executed `sudo python setup.py install`
3. ran tests by executing `nosetests pandas`

Please keep in mind I am a total newbie to python. Any insights on why my install failed would be greatly appreciated. Below is a snippet of the errors. The entire log can be found at [Error log](http://encodable.com/uploaddemo/files/Pandas_install_test.txt)

Results:

Ran 1498 tests in 55.011s
FAILED (SKIP=4, errors=91, failures=14)

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_generate (test_daterange.TestGeneration)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/tests/test_daterange.py", line 20, in test_generate
    rng2 = list(generate_range(START, END, timeRule='WEEKDAY'))
TypeError: generate_range() got an unexpected keyword argument 'timeRule'
```

@wesm - thanks for your quick reply. Next time I will definitely use the mailing list. So I actually backtracked... installed the official 0.5.0 release and compiled from source. I received 3 errors (see below). I did not experience any problems running `sudo python setup.py install`

```
======================================================================
ERROR: testForSeries (pandas.stats.tests.test_ols.TestPanelOLS)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/stats/tests/test_ols.py", line 472, in testForSeries
    self.series_x, self.series_y)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/stats/tests/test_ols.py", line 565, in checkForSeries
    reference = ols(y=series_y, x=series_x, **kwds)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/stats/interface.py", line 133, in ols
    return klass(**kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/stats/ols.py", line 36, in __init__
    import scikits.statsmodels.api as sm
ImportError: No module named api

======================================================================
ERROR: testNonPooled (pandas.stats.tests.test_ols.TestPanelOLS)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/stats/tests/test_ols.py", line 522, in testNonPooled
    self.checkNonPooled(y=self.panel_y, x=self.panel_x)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/stats/tests/test_ols.py", line 528, in checkNonPooled
    result = ols(y=y, x=x, pool=False, **kwds)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/stats/interface.py", line 133, in ols
    return klass(**kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/stats/plm.py", line 780, in __init__
    nw_overlap=nw_overlap)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/stats/interface.py", line 133, in ols
    return klass(**kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/stats/ols.py", line 36, in __init__
    import scikits.statsmodels.api as sm
ImportError: No module named api

======================================================================
ERROR: test_auto_rolling_window_type (pandas.stats.tests.test_ols.TestPanelOLS)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/stats/tests/test_ols.py", line 604, in test_auto_rolling_window_type
    window_model = ols(y=y, x=data, window=20, min_periods=10)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/stats/interface.py", line 133, in ols
    return klass(**kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/stats/ols.py", line 521, in __init__
    OLS.__init__(self, y=y, x=x, **self._args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/stats/ols.py", line 36, in __init__
    import scikits.statsmodels.api as sm
ImportError: No module named api
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was resolved by:

1) installing the pandas 0.6.0 release which Wes made available November 25/2011.

2) removing the existing scikits package, which is bundled with EPD 7.1 (version 0.2) and installing the latest release using 'easy_install -U scikits.statsmodels'.

The above were suggestions made by Wes and folks on the pystatsmodel mailing list (thank you to all).

Answer (score 1):

Best place to ask this question would be on the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/group/pystatsmodels) (luckily Google Alerts let me know about this right away!). It looks like your install failed and it's still using pandas 0.3.0. Were there any errors when you ran `python setup.py install`? You may have to upgrade your Cython installation if you're building from a git snapshot (`sudo easy_install -U Cython`). If that doesn't work, try nuking your existing pandas install:

`sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas`

and reinstalling. The tarball on [PyPI](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pandas) includes pre-built Cython sources. If you're building from source anyway I recommend building from the head revision on git anyway. I'm days away from releasing pandas 0.6.0.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. Next time I will definitely use the mailing list. So I actually backtracked... installed the official 0.5.0 release and compiled from source for MacOS. I received 3 errors (see updated original post). I did not experience any problems running sudo python setup.py install. Appreciate the help. Thank you